# Ruby On Rails Basic Show method failed still

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In this block of code, i want to put a button "edit" inside the "show" views. However, due to some reason, it did not works out

My home_controller.rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController

```
  def index
    @inputs = Person.all
  end

  def new
    @input = Person.new
  end

  def create
    @input = Person.new(input_params)
    respond_to do |x|
    if @input.save
        x.html {redirect_to :action => 'index'}
    else
        x.html {render :action => 'new'}
    end

   end
  end

  def show
    @input = Person.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @input = Person.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @input = Person.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |x|
      if @input.update(input_params)
        x.html {redirect_to :action => 'index'}
      else
        x.html {render :edit}
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def input_params
    params.require(:inputs).permit(:name, :weight, :height, :color, :age)
  end
end
```

My routes file only have two lines:

```
resources: home
root 'home#index'
```

My index.html.erb

```
   <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing</h1>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th> Weight</th>
            <th> Height</th>
            <th> Color</th>
            <th> Age</th>
            <th colspan="3"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @inputs.each do |person| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= person.name %></td>
            <td><%= person.weight %></td>
            <td><%= person.height %></td>
            <td><%= person.color %></td>
            <td><%= person.age %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Show',home_path(person.id) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_home_path(person.id) %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
     </tbody>
 </table>
 <br>
 <%= link_to 'New Test', new_home_path %>
```

my show.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @input.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Weight:</strong>
  <%= @input.weight %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Height:</strong>
  <%= @input.height %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Color:</strong>
  <%= @input.color %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Age:</strong>
  <%= @input.age %>
</p>

<% link_to 'Edit', edit_home_path(@input) %>
<%= link_to 'Back', home_index_path%>
```

My form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @input, url: {action: "update"} do |person| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= person.label :name %><br>
    <%= person.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= person.label :weight %><br>
    <%= person.number_field :weight %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= person.label :height %><br>
    <%= person.number_field :height %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= person.label :color %><br>
    <%= person.text_field :color %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= person.label :age %><br>
    <%= person.number_field :age %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= person.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Editing Data</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= link_to 'Show', home_path %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', home_index_path %>
```

The error i get is:
[image: It suppose to give me a Edit button, but actually it did not show up, confused]

My code `<% link_to 'Edit', edit_home_path(@input) %>` is point the Edit button to the route home/edit with the obeject @input, that is how i understand it, but it still not working.
Any idea how can i fix this?
Many thanks

Comment: It seems like your link_to is wrong. You can do like this:
<td><%= link_to 'Show', home_path(person.id) %></td> inside index.html.erb

Comment: Hi Sachin, thanks for your help, i get over with that routes stuff, however, i got another problem with the show.html.erb itself.I would post the picture at the end. to my understanding, after the show is call inside the index action. The person will go in the show action, and for each inputs, i going to read the attribute, however, it is not the case, it is both wrong for calling inputs.name or person.name

Comment: the error indicate NoMethodError in Home#show undefined method 'name' for nil:Nilclass[]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your `show.html.erb`. You need to change `@person` to `@input` as you have `@input` defined in your `show` method

Comment: Hi all, i am a newbie to ror, just struggling with link_to method
For example i have a controller home and action include:index,show

Here is how i used link to:
    <%= link_to 'Back', index_home_path%>
However, it did not turns out to be valid,In my routes.rb, i have
resources: home
root 'home#index'

My problem is how can i efficiently used link_to without having such problem and what should i care when writing this??

Comment: the error is NameError in Home#show undefined local variable or method `index_home_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f491417f6d8>:0x007f4916b10ba0>

Comment: You need to give it as `<%= link_to 'Back', home_path%>`

Comment: what is home_path means exactly? i think index_home_path making more sense, it is identical to controller: 'home', action: 'index' which would point the button to index page. I just confused

Comment: actually i try your code, it kind of works, but it did not send me back to index page but rather stay on the show page still

Comment: no worries, i just figure it out it should be <%= link_to 'Back', home_index_path%> to send me back to index page hahaha many thanks for your help, wish you have a good night